# Display problems in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: 15.04

I have recently updated Ubuntu from 14.10 to 15.04. The problem is that my desktop wallpaper looks blurred and a discontinuos line comes to right side of my desktop.

This problem wasn't there in previous version of Ubuntu.

I am using ubuntu 15.04 with unity 7.3.2

How should I proceed?

[image]

Also these random lines appears on right side of almost all windows

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was a new installation of Ubuntu Studio 15.10 64bit, on a Dell Optiplex 760 dual core Intel, 6GB RAM

Display adapter:
Intel Corporation 4 Series Chipset Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 03)

What worked:

1. I installed Intel Driver Update Tool from
   https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intelr-graphics-installer-linux-1.0.8
2. Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist upgrade`

What DIDN'T WORK:

- installing nvidia drivers
- installing CompizConfig Settings Manager

best

Answer (score 1):

You are probably using an alpha or a beta version Ubuntu 15.04. These glitches are normal. I advise you to be patient for another 3 days till the stable version of Ubuntu 15.04 gets released (23/4/2015).

Comment: How do you update the beta version to stable one after it is releases ???

Comment: this link show you how: http://www.noobslab.com/2015/04/how-to-upgrade-to-ubuntu-1504-vivid.html. I hope it helps you

Comment: Yes ok thanks ...... Solved all the problems also!

Comment: happy to hear that

Comment: This problem appears again everytime i login the wallpaper gets distorted i have to change the wallpaper to fix this...

Comment: maybe you need to update your graphic card driver, go to System Setting, then Softwares and Updates, then additional drivers, then here you will find all list of drivers available

Comment: There is no additional drivers available there.......

Comment: Can you provide me with your PC configuration?

Comment: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_UiBc8KYwP5ekRzTFNCNUVrQlk/view?usp=sharing) Here you go sir.. If you need any more info please tell me

Answer (score 0):

May be it is not right thing to put the my solution here or it will help to other also but, I was also facing Display issue today with **Ubuntu 15.04** and I did following steps through the terminal:

```
 # cat /etc/lsb-release
 DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
 DISTRIB_RELEASE=15.04
 DISTRIB_CODENAME=vivid
 DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 15.04"


sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
sudo restart gdm
```

*restart: Unable to connect to Upstart: Failed to connect to socket /com/ubuntu/upstart: Connection refused*

Restart Ubuntu Machine.

The issue has been fixed Now.